# .NetCore 2.2: web.config -> appsettings conversion for third party tools

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web-config, siteminder

C#, .NetCore 2.2, Visual Studio 2019

I am having a really hard time getting used to the `web.config` to `appsettings.json` conversion process.  Yes, I have read the docs but there is something I am missing.

I have been told that there is no 1:1 conversion from `web.config` to `appsettings.json`.  I have read that there is nothing particularly special about the `appsettings.json` file and that the info there could be in nearly any other format / storage system.  I have read that `appsettings` is just read by whatever policy provider needs to read it.

How do you know what policy providers exist or which one(s) you need?

In ny current case I have an existing, older project that uses a third party web base authentication service called "Siteminder".  The use case is very simple: the older app has a small set of controllers.  Siteminder is configured (server level not app level) to monitor request URLs.  If a request goes to "https://thing.company.com/Auth/" then Siteminder looks for its auth token and either interrupts the request and challenges the visitor for credentials or validates and passes the request on.

My new app should work the same way.

The old app has a `web.config` that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
        <system.webServer>
            <handlers>
                <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" 
                     modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" 
                     resourceType="Unspecified" />
                <add name="handler-wa-32" path="*" verb="*" 
                     modules="IsapiModule"
                     scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files\CA\webagent\win32\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" 
                     resourceType="Unspecified"
                     requireAccess="None" preCondition="classicMode,bitness32" />
                <add name="CASiteMinderWebAgentHandler-fcc-32" 
                     path="*.fcc" verb="*" 
                     modules="CASiteMinderWebagentModule-32"
                     resourceType="Unspecified" 
                     preCondition="integratedMode,bitness32" />


                <!-- 10 additional, similar "CASiteMinderWebAgentHandler-???-??" handlers !-->


            </handlers>
            <modules>
                <add name="CASiteMinderWebagentModule" 
                     preCondition="integratedMode,bitness64" />
                <add name="CASiteMinderWebagentModule-32" 
                     preCondition="integratedMode,bitness32" />
            </modules>
            <isapiFilters>
                <filter name="SiteMinder Agent" 
                        path="C:\Program Files\CA\webagent\win64\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" enabled="true"
                        preCondition="classicMode,bitness64" />
                <filter name="SiteMinder Agent-32" 
                        path="C:\Program Files\CA\webagent\win32\bin\ISAPI6WebAgent.dll" enabled="true"
                        preCondition="classicMode,bitness32" />
            </isapiFilters>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

I have not found Siteminder docs on using .Net Core 2.x yet.  I have no idea how to let my app, the web server, whatever, know about these settingS.

It feels like there is a missing section of documentation.  How do you port this sort of config over to `appsettings` and let whatever systems, services, providers know about them?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not HTTP module-based. There's an ASP.NET Core HTTP Module, but that's just for hosting ASP.NET Core apps via IIS, and it serves to just proxy out to the Core app. If you're hosting in IIS, then you could presumably configure the "SiteMinder" module at the IIS level, and it shouldn't need to worry about ASP.NET Core at all. However, if there's tie into the actual framework (which was a possibility with ASP.NET sites), then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

SiteMinder does not provide plugins for .Net Core. Further, HTTP Modules written for IIS/.Net 4.x are not compatible with .Net Core anyway, which has a very different request processing pipeline.

I've done a fair amount of work with enabling "traditional" access managers to work with .Net Core. Its tricky. (disclaimer, shameless plug here...). My company's product provides a universal REST-based interface for use with SSO products including SiteMinder, and provides .Net and .Net Core libraries (as well as Java, C, C++, and a variety of web and app servers). You might ask your SiteMinder owners to take a look, the link is on my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like my best solution is to continue to use `web.config` for Siteminder.  It works.  I was hoping that there was a way around that though.